# I opened Xcode 4 project in Xcode 5. When I open the view that was opened in XC5, the labels and buttons are not showing, How can I fix this?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xcode5

I have a project that is xcode 4.6.3, and I inadvertently opened the project in xcode 5. There was a xib open, and so it changed it to default to ios7. I already changed it to open with xcode 4.6 in the interface builder section so that isn't the problem. The problem is that xcode 5 changed the UI so that now the labels and buttons do not show on the XIB. I can see them in the object explorer, but clicking on them does not bring them into focus on the XIB. How can I make them show on the screen again?

Comment: Well, if your're using git "git checkout -- ." and start over :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me too. Check the X and the Y frame values for your labels, buttons, etc. For me they were set to crazy values like -1543 for some reason. I haven't figured out why yet. But if you change the X and Y values back to something within the view's frame, they'll show up. Hope this helps.